# IndexError while performing Subqueries on django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have a post list for which I am trying to retrieve some data from its related models, to display in a post list.
The data I need is the latest comment made, the user, the user group and the date and text of the comment.

I am trying to achieve this result with this complex annotate query:

```py
all_posts=Post.objects.all()
posts = all_posts.annotate(
    comment_count=Count('comment'),
    g_origin=Coalesce(Subquery(
        PostGroup.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).values('group')
    ), Value(0)),
    latest_comment_author=Coalesce(Subquery(
        PostComment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).values('user__user')
    ), Value(''),
    latest_comment_created=Coalesce(Subquery(
        PostComment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created').values('created')
    ), Value('')),
    latest_comment_text=Coalesce(Subquery(
        PostComment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created').values('text')
    ), Value(''))
)
```

But this is just resulting in `IndexError: list index out of range`, but looks like the error is being originated within Django's internal files.

Some posts could have no comments, no user or no data, but I used to think I could solve that with Coalesce(x, default_value, but it's still giving the error)

I also tried to reduce it to just

```py
all_posts=Post.objects.all()
posts = all_posts.annotate(
    comment_count=Count('comment')
)
```

or to

```py
all_posts=Post.objects.all()
posts = all_posts.annotate(
    g_origin=Coalesce(Subquery(
        PostGroup.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).values('group')
    ), Value(0)),
)
```

But still, it's giving the error.

What could the problem be?

Here's the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 85, in process_view
    response = panel.process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/profiling.py", line 160, in process_view
    return self.profiler.runcall(view_func, *args, **view_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/cProfile.py", line 121, in runcall
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/collaboration_tool/views.py", line 1188, in get
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 173, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1121, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 62, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 847, in results_iter
    row = self.apply_converters(row, converters)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 830, in apply_converters
    value = row[pos]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am using Python 3.7 and Django 1.11 and no, I can't upgrade.

EDIT: This is the traceback I obtain if I try to make the same query in the Django shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py", line 224, in catch_format_error
    r = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py", line 702, in __call__
    printer.pretty(obj)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py", line 402, in pretty
    return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py", line 697, in _repr_pprint
    output = repr(obj)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 226, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1121, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 62, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 847, in results_iter
    row = self.apply_converters(row, converters)
  File "/home/myUser/Desktop/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 830, in apply_converters
    value = row[pos]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It might help if you add your *full* traceback.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: error show problem with `list index` but I don't see any `list` and index (like `list[index]`) in your code - so maybe problem is in different place? But you didn't show FULL error message so we can't confirm it.